# pythonic way to identify corresponding transactions from lists

Tags: python

As you can see from the messages below, I have two dicts that are corresponding transactions. The first is the open trade, and the second is close trade. To match the transactions there is a tradeID provided in both dicts which in this case is `'id': '935074'`. I need a way to match the transactions based on the trade id and then match the transactions and pick out elements from the dict like trans, action, time, etc.

```
{'id': '935074', 'accountID': '###', 'userID': 22347481, 'batchID': '935073', 'requestID': '42961078263050223', 'time': '2022-05-17T10:50:44.448321350Z', 'type': 'ORDER_FILL', 'orderID': '935073', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'units': '1', 'requestedUnits': '1', 'price': '1.05167', 'pl': '0.0000', 'quotePL': '0', 'financing': '0.0000', 'baseFinancing': '0', 'commission': '0.0000', 'accountBalance': '10570876.0435', 'gainQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '0.797985392777', 'lossQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '0.806005346473', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0001', 'fullVWAP': '1.05167', 'reason': 'MARKET_ORDER', 'tradeOpened': {'price': '1.05167', 'tradeID': '935074', 'units': '1', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0001', 'initialMarginRequired': '0.0281', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000'}, 'fullPrice': {'closeoutBid': '1.05150', 'closeoutAsk': '1.05171', 'timestamp': '2022-05-17T10:50:43.073152821Z', 'bids': [{'price': '1.05154', 'liquidity': '1000000'}, {'price': '1.05153', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05152', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05150', 'liquidity': '5000000'}], 'asks': [{'price': '1.05167', 'liquidity': '1000000'}, {'price': '1.05169', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05170', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05171', 'liquidity': '5000000'}]}, 'homeConversionFactors': {'gainQuoteHome': {'factor': '0.79798539277707'}, 'lossQuoteHome': {'factor': '0.80600534647333'}, 'gainBaseHome': {'factor': '0.83916310'}, 'lossBaseHome': {'factor': '0.84759690'}}, 'plHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'baseFinancingHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'homeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000'}

{'id': '935076', 'accountID': '##', 'userID': 22347481, 'batchID': '935075', 'requestID': '42961078711973981', 'time': '2022-05-17T10:52:31.825941345Z', 'type': 'ORDER_FILL', 'orderID': '935075', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'units': '-1', 'requestedUnits': '-1', 'price': '1.05128', 'pl': '-0.0003', 'quotePL': '-0.00039', 'financing': '0.0000', 'baseFinancing': '0.00000000000000', 'commission': '0.0000', 'accountBalance': '10570876.0432', 'gainQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '0.798094203338', 'lossQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '0.806115250607', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0001', 'fullVWAP': '1.05128', 'reason': 'MARKET_ORDER_POSITION_CLOSEOUT', 'tradesClosed': [{'tradeID': '935074', 'units': '-1', 'realizedPL': '-0.0003', 'financing': '0.0000', 'baseFinancing': '0.00000000000000', 'price': '1.05128', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0001', 'plHomeConversionCost': '-0.00000154152186', 'baseFinancingHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'homeConversionCost': '-0.00000154152186'}], 'fullPrice': {'closeoutBid': '1.05124', 'closeoutAsk': '1.05145', 'timestamp': '2022-05-17T10:52:27.750681259Z', 'bids': [{'price': '1.05128', 'liquidity': '1000000'}, {'price': '1.05127', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05126', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05124', 'liquidity': '5000000'}], 'asks': [{'price': '1.05141', 'liquidity': '1000000'}, {'price': '1.05143', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05144', 'liquidity': '2000000'}, {'price': '1.05145', 'liquidity': '5000000'}]}, 'homeConversionFactors': {'gainQuoteHome': {'factor': '0.79809420333777'}, 'lossQuoteHome': {'factor': '0.80611525060749'}, 'gainBaseHome': {'factor': '0.83908350'}, 'lossBaseHome': {'factor': '0.84751650'}}, 'plHomeConversionCost': '-0.00000154152186', 'baseFinancingHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'homeConversionCost': '-0.00000154152186'}
```

I developed the following for-loop that picks out the tradeID from both messages:

```
if i['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL':
        print(i)
         if 'tradeOpened' in i:
             opn_trade = i['tradeOpened']
             opn_trade_id=opn_trade['tradeID']
   
         if 'tradesClosed' in i:
             cls_trade = i['tradesClosed']
             cls_trade_id = cls_trade[0]['tradeID']
```

But I don't know how to combine both dict so I can pick out specific elements.

Comment: I don't see two lists. Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: Apologies two dictionaries not lists

Comment: can't you create a list/tuple from those two dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating 2 lists and using zip to join them